# strongify and weakify causing issues

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a code that does something like this:

```
@weakify(self);
dispatch_group_notify(myGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    @strongify(self);
    [self doSomething];
});
```

However, the "self" seems to be actually nil inside of this block. i didn't even know this was possible. I thought that the `@weakify` virtually creates a weak reference to `self`, lets call this `__weakSelf`. then when i use `@strongify`, it assigns a local variable to `__weakSelf`.

why is `self` nil at the line `[self doSomething]` ?? does this mean that `self` already got released because `dispatch_group_notify` isn't held on to by `self`  or something?? and thus `self` gets dealloc'ed at any time? (such as when my block is actually run)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask:

> why is `self` `nil` at the line `[self doSomething]` ??

Because it was `nil` before it got to the `@strongify(self)` line. I.e. it was deallocated before the notify block even started.

> does this mean that `self` already got released because `dispatch_group_notify` isn't held on to by `self` or something??

Yep. Or, more accurately, `self` was already released by the time the block specified by `dispatch_group_notify` was invoked.

That's the whole purpose of the `weakify`: Make sure that the occurrences of `self` inside the block of `dispatch_group_notify` don't result in `self` being retained. The purpose of the `strongify` inside the block is if `self` is not released yet, make sure it isn't released while the block runs, but if it's released *after* `weakify`, but *before* you reach the `strongify` line, then go ahead and let it get deallocated and let `self` be `nil`.

--

A typical use-case is when one initiates a bunch of async requests and have a notify block that updates the UI when the downloads are done. You might use `weakify` to the reference to the view controller, so if you dismiss the view controller before the downloads are done, the notify block won't hang on to it (which makes sense, if the user dismisses the view controller, there's no point in hanging on to a view controller reference to update a view that is no longer present). But you might use `strongify` inside that block so that if the view controller wasn't dismissed before the notify block started, make sure it isn't released *while* the notify block is running (this is often a less critical issue, but sometimes is important).

Comment: so the correct solution is to remove both the `@weakify` and `@strongify` in his scenario, because the grand discpatcher will already hold on to a reference of `self`; yet won't cause cycle retains?

Comment: No, the strong reference cycle is resolved as soon as that notify block completes, so you don't need to worry about that, in this situation. Bottom line, if you really need `self` retained until the block is called, yes, remove `weakify` and `strongify`, and you'll be OK. But, if you don't want `self` retained until that point, then use `weakify`/`strongify`.

Comment: @Rob , will it not cause any retain cycle if we remove `weakify` and `strongify` and `self` itself being `strong` ?

Comment: Not in this case. You have a strong reference cycle if A (i.e. `self`) has strong reference to B (the block) and B also has strong reference back to A. But `self` does not have strong reference to the block. GCD does, and it releases it after the block runs. So, no cycle. Now, there is a separate question whether it is appropriate for `self` to be retained until the group is done. So, in this case, it's not a strong reference cycle question but rather merely "if all other references to `self` Have been resolved, is it important for `self` to hang around until the GCD group is done or not?"